# Error while running 'pip install prophet'

Tags: python, pip, facebook-prophet

I am trying to run `pip install prophet` as I am trying to make a prophet forecast on a set of data that I have ready. However, when running the command in the terminal it seems to give me an error from the point of where it says `Installing dependecies...`

```
C:\Users\jongy\Documents\GitHub\COVID-19-Research>pip install prophet     
Collecting prophet
  Using cached prophet-1.1.2.tar.gz (67 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [69 lines of output]
      Collecting setuptools>=64
        Using cached setuptools-67.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.38.4-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
      Collecting cmdstanpy>=1.0.4
        Using cached cmdstanpy-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (83 kB)
      Collecting numpy>=1.21
        Using cached numpy-1.24.1.tar.gz (10.9 MB)
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error

        Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
        exit code: 1

        [40 lines of output]
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
            main()
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
            json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 112, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
            backend = _build_backend()
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 77, in _build_backend
            obj = import_module(mod_path)
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 887, in exec_module
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
          File "C:\Users\jongy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-rcrx6svy\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 242, in <module>
            monkey.patch_all()
          File "C:\Users\jongy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-rcrx6svy\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 99, in patch_all
            patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler()
          File "C:\Users\jongy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-rcrx6svy\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 162, in patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler
            patch_func(*msvc9('find_vcvarsall'))
          File "C:\Users\jongy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-rcrx6svy\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 149, in patch_params
            mod = import_module(mod_name)
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 887, in exec_module
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
          File "C:\Users\jongy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-rcrx6svy\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 295, in <module>
            raise DistutilsPlatformError("VC %0.1f is not supported by this module" % VERSION)
        distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: VC 6.0 is not supported by this module
        [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error

      Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
      exit code: 1

      See above for output.

      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

After looking through the error I thought that maybe my python version was the issue and tried using Python 3.10 instead of 3.11. However, the error consistently popped up. 
I am also aware that `fbprophet` exists but as I am using a windows computer I cannot use `fbprophet`. As well as, after checking the facebook prophet documentation it said to run `python -m pip install prophet` which I did but the program still gave me the same error.

Can someone tell me the reason behind this issue so that I can solve it?

Many thanks,
John

Comment: The root error seems to be `VC 6.0 is not supported by this module`.  From what I can see, 6.0 is quite old.  Are you able to upgrade your version of Visual C?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by upgrading the version of Visual C. Do you mean upating Visual Studio Community?

Comment: The error message is `VC 6.0 is not supported by this module`, and it came from a module named `msvc9compiler.py`.  I assume it is talking about Visual C.  If not, then I don't know what else to suggest.